# karaf not displaying any error while component factory example

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, osgi-bundle, karaf

i have tried component factory example from this [link](https://github.com/sully6768/karaf-scr-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/scr/examples/componentfactory/ExampleComponentFactoryManager.java). 
interface:

```
package com.java.examplefactoryservice;

public interface ExampleFactoryService {
    public void start();

    public void stop();
}
```

factory provider:

```
package com.java.examplecomponentfactoryserviceprovider;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;

import com.java.examplefactoryservice.ExampleFactoryService;

@Component(name = "ExampleComponentFactoryServiceProvider", factory = "example.factory.provider")
public class ExampleComponentFactoryServiceProvider implements ExampleFactoryService {

    @Activate
    public void activate(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        System.out.println("Actiavted!!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Started !!!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Stopped!!!");
    }

}
```

factory manager:

```
package com.java.examplecomponentfatorymanager;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentFactory;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentInstance;

import com.java.examplefactoryservice.ExampleFactoryService;

@Component(name = "ExampleComponentFactoryManager", enabled = true, immediate = true)
public class ExampleComponentFactoryManager {

    @Reference(target = "(component.factory=example.factory.provider)", bind = "setFactory", unbind = "unsetFactory")
    private ComponentFactory factory;

    private ComponentInstance instance;

    private ExampleFactoryService service;

    @Activate
    public void activate(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        System.out.println("activate in manager !!!!");
        instance = factory.newInstance(null);
        service = (ExampleFactoryService) instance.getInstance();
        System.out.println("service  = " + service.toString());
    }

    public void setFactory(final ComponentFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
        System.out.println("setfactory called");
    }

    public void unsetFactory(ComponentFactory factory) {
        this.factory = null;
        System.out.println("Unset factory called");
    }

}
```

Everything compiled fine and installed in karaf 2.3.10. factory is registered successfully. But nothing has been displayed.

karaf output:

```
[  71] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] osgi.cmpn (4.3.1.201210102024)
[  79] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] testI (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
[  80] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] testImpl (0.0.3.SNAPSHOT)
[ 110] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] Apache Felix Declarative Services (1.6.0)
[ 140] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] ExampleFactoryService (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
[ 152] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] ExampleComponentFactoryServiceProvider (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
[ 158] [Active     ] [            ] [   80] ExampleComponentFatoryManager (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
```

scr:list output

```
[9   ] [FACTORY         ] ExampleComponentFactoryServiceProvider
```

scr:details

```
scr:deactivate    scr:details
karaf@root> scr:details ExampleComponentFactoryServiceProvider
Component Details
  Name                : ExampleComponentFactoryServiceProvider
  State               : FACTORY
  Properties          :
    service.vendor=The Apache Software Foundation
    component.factory=example.factory.provider
    component.name=ExampleComponentFactoryServiceProvider
References
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ExampleComponentFatoryManager</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExampleComponentFatoryManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <version>2.3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *,
                            javax.servlet*;version="[2.5,4)"
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ExampleFactoryService</groupId>
            <artifactId>ExampleFactoryService</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Initially i tried in karaf command line to install a bundle instead of name it displays the absolute path of the bundle. After sometime i tried by putting the bundle in deploy it shows the exact name of the bundle. 
I didn't understand the behaviour of karaf why it is not showing the bundle name while doing proper command line installation. And it is not at all showing any errors[dependency/compilation/wiredexecption]. Can anybody please tell me what is wrong in the bundle?

Comment: Is that the whole output from `scr:list`? The `ExampleComponentFactoryManager` is missing

Comment: yes. only one bundle i have installed. ExampleComponentFactoryManager  is not displayed in scr:list.

Comment: @Neil , Atleast i am expecting the SOP will be printed. But nothing is printed. Also if i install it via cmd line bundle name is not displayed instead the absolute path is displayed. I didn't understand the behaviour of Karaf. Is this an performance issue in karaf or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I think there is an error in the construction of the bundle, because the `ExampleComponentFactoryManager` doesn't appear at all. However I can only guess, because only the Java source code is posted.

Comment: Construction of bundle does nothing. Because it is deployed properly with the name as expected. If you want i can post the pom.xml.

Comment: @Neil, Thank you very much . The problem is with the pom.xml. <packagin>bundle</packaging> is missing in my pom.xml. Because of that it just makes an ordinary jar file instead of osgi jar file.

Comment: When i try to start the bundle activate method is called twice and two objects of service is created? i don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

you can go for import aQute.bnd.annotation instead 
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations   for karaf.

refer below code

```
@Component(name="ExampleComponentFactoryManager",immediate=true,enabled=true)
public class ExampleComponentFactoryManager
{

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleComponentFactoryManager.class);

    private ComponentFactory factory;

   // @Reference(target = "(component.factory=example.factory.provider)",unbind = "unsetFactory")
    //private ComponentFactory factory;

    private ComponentInstance instance;

    private ExampleFactoryService service;

    @Activate
    public void activate(Map<String, Object> properties) {
        LOG.info("activation factorymanager");
        instance=factory.newInstance(null);
        service =(ExampleFactoryService)instance.getInstance();
        LOG.info("service instance  from factory "+service.toString());

    }
    @Reference(target = "(component.factory=example.factory.provider)",unbind = "unsetFactory")
    public void setFactory(final ComponentFactory factory) {
        LOG.info("set Factory");
        this.factory = factory;
        System.out.println("setfactory called");
    }

    public void unsetFactory(ComponentFactory factory) {
        this.factory = null;
        System.out.println("Unset factory called");
    }
}
```